# Unexplained DNS traffic using USB-Ethernet adapter

Tags: macos, usb, dns, ethernet, malware

I have a USB-Ethernet adapter, whose brand I do not wish to disclose. When I plug it in (on a Mac), after a while, I start receiving a large amount of incoming DNS responses. It accumulates to gigabytes per day, if I let it. This doesn't happen with the Mac's WiFi connection, nor with Apple's Thunderbolt-Ethernet adapter (nor with this one if I unplug the ethernet cable, even though the Mac's WiFi is kept on).

This can't be normal, but I don't understand neither what it is, nor whether it's malicious. I've had other USB-Ethernet adapters that show no such issue.

Some months back (in a previous install, previous version of macOS) I did capture the odd traffic and that's how I know it's DNS responses - it's an incoming, rather than an outgoing, issue - but I don't remember anymore what command line wizardry I did use.

What can I do to investigate or solve the issue? Maybe this is a question for another site?

Comment: Can you take a new packet capture and post it somewhere and edit your question to link to it? If you forgot how you did your packet capture, here's one way: `sudo tcpdump -nei en2 -w problem.pcap`. Then let it run for as long as you'd like, and then hit Ctrl-C to stop it. Then find the "problem.pcap" file it created, and upload that. If you want a GUI way to do all this, download Wireshark. There's no easy explanation for why an arbitrary third party Ethernet dongle would start receiving tons of DNS responses, so it would help to see the actual traffic to see if that's really what's going on.

Comment: BTW, I used "en2" as a placeholder. Replace it with the actual enX identifier of your Ethernet dongle. Use `ifconfig` to see all the network interfaces on your system, to help you determine the "enX"-style ID of your dongle.

Comment: @Spiff now that I'm on it, it's behaving normally. I don't know how long it will be before I manage to get a meaningful capture (days?), but I'll post it, thanks for the instructions.